# Regular Expression in XSLT

Tags: css, xml, xslt

I have an XSLT function that takes a regular expression as a parameter but the XSLT parser does not like it.

Here is the code:

```
<xsl:value-of select='ns:RegexReplace($variable, "", "style=\"\w+\:\s\w+;\"")' disable-output-escaping='yes' />
```

I found this:
http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/06/04/tr.html <-- but it is using what I am and seems to work (for them). Do I just have a rubbish parser??

Is there any way of doing this? 
Or, a way of forcing an element to ignore inline style via a CSS trick?

Comment: From your sample ccode it looks as if you are using an XSLT extension. What kind of extension is that? And for a solution it helps to know which platform you are own as there are platform-specific extensions available for regular expressions.

Comment: @divo - The XSLT extension is irrelevant as I am just talking about passing in the parameter. Unfortunately I don't know the parser details.

Comment: You probably need to replace the quotes inside your expression with an XML entity (&quot;)

Comment: The sample that you link to is about XSLT 2.0. If that is your platform you should state that clearly. XSLT 1.0 is still broadly used and is a lot different from XSLT 2.0. What parser are you using and what is the error message that you get?

Comment: ...And if possible could you please post a short sample where this problem occurs? That would it make much easier to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be trying to include quotes in a quote-delimited XPath string literal by escaping them with a backslash. That does not work.

In [XPath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath) (XSLT 1), there is no nice way to do this. You may need to resort to tricks like defining a variable which holds a single quote character and using the `concat` function to create your string:

```
<xsl:variable name='quot' select="'&quot;'"/>
<xsl:value-of select='concat("a string with a quote ", $quot, " character")'/>
```

In [XPath 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/) (XSLT 2), you can escape a quote with another quote:

```
<xsl:value-of select='"a string with a quote "" character"'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It occurs to me that you may be trying to remove `style` attributes. If that is the case, then string replacement is not going to help you.

You can remove style attributes for example by writing a template which matches them and outputs nothing:

```
<xsl:template match="@style"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a function that returns the inline style as text and hence cannot be removed this way.